# Socket.io how to list sockets in a room by nickname

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to node.js and javascript. I'm using socket.io and trying to list sockets connected in a given room. When a socket connects I give it a nickname:

```
io.use(function (socket, next) {
  var handshakeUserid = socket.request._query.userid;
  socket.nickname = handshakeUserid;
  next();
});
```

With this code I can get the id's of the sockets:

```
 for (socketID in io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[room_name].sockets) {
   console.log(socketID);
 }
```

But how can I access the nickname property in this loop? Trying `socketID.nickname`, or `socketID[nickname]` will trow an error nickname is not define.

Comment: I tried to use this method, did not got it to work. I solved it as a hack created an mapping object  `const clients = {}; clients[socket.id] = handshakeUserId` and then I just use clients[socket.id] when I need my nickname!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some debugging and you can access your field by using:

```
 for (socketID in io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[room_name].sockets) {
   const nickname = io.nsps['/'].connected[socketID].nickname;
   // do stuff with nickname
 }
```

`nsps` object has the `adapter` and `connected` properties.

Connected has a list of all the socket.id and the data that you decorated in the middleware.

Comment: Glad to help! have a nice day!